# Accessing has_one relationship through JSON with React.js and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs

I'm creating a simple comment form using React.js inside my Rails application. When I submit a comment, I'm unable to render the author's name with the comment.

```
TypeError: comment.user is undefined 
React.createElement(Comment, {username:  comment.user.name, body: comment.body key: comment.id}
```

**commentlist.jsx.erb**

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function ( comment ) {
      return <Comment username={ comment.user.name } body={ comment.body } key={ comment.id }  />
    });

    return (
      <div className="comment-list">
        { commentNodes }
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

**commentscontroller.erb**

```
  def index
    @presenter = {
        :comments => Comment.last(5),
        :form => {
            :action => comments_path,
            :csrf_param => request_forgery_protection_token,
            :csrf_token => form_authenticity_token
        }
    }
  end



  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.commentable = @event
    @comment.body = comment_params[:body]
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save

    if request.xhr?
      render :json => Comment.last(5)
    else
      redirect_to comments_path
    end
  end
```

**comments/index.html.erb**

```
<%= react_component('CommentBox',
                    {:presenter => @presenter.to_json(:include => :user)},
                    {:prerender => true}) %>
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Just let me know if I'm missing any code samples.

**UPDATE**

This doesn't answer my question, but it's a solution. I added an `author` method to the comment model that returns the commenter's name, so I can now access the name directly from the comment.

```
  def author
    User.find(self.user_id).name
  end
```

Though I'd still like to know how to access through an association.

Comment: Does comment belong_to User in the comment model?

Comment: @JimmyBaker Yes it does. I made sure the comment list and form were working before trying to implement React.

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_json
  {:author => self.user.name}
end
```

And wherever you are rendering json object just call Comment.last.as_json

Refer http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/